# Specify environment on docker-compose up

Tags: docker-compose

Why is it not possible to say for example `docker-compose up -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=bla`?
If my application connects to a mysql server it would be nice to inject that same password into the application container as well. Is this somehow possible?